# Composer + Rocketeer + ZF2- Cannot install Rocketeer due to requirements conflict

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php, rocketeer

Can somebody can tell me how to fix this?

Rocketeer installs just fine in empty dir, but not along with my existing project, don't know w why.

What is requiering that installation?

```
 - Installation request for symfony/console == 2.6.6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.6.6].
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

**command**

```
composer require anahkiasen/rocketeer
```

**output**

```
Using version ^2.2 for anahkiasen/rocketeer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for anahkiasen/rocketeer ^2.2 -> satisfiable by anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/console v2.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v2.6.6
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.0 requires illuminate/console ~4.2 -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.1 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.12 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.16 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.17 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.2 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.3 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.4 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.5 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.6 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.7 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.8 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - illuminate/console v4.2.9 requires symfony/console 2.5.* -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.1, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.10, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.11, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.12, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.2, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.3, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.4, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.5, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.6, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.7, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.8, v2.6.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v2.5.9, v2.6.6].
    - Installation request for symfony/console == 2.6.6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v2.6.6].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: This log want to say to you that dependencies from those libraries doesn't match. Some modules need `symfony/console` `v2.6.*`, but other require `2.5.*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why doesn't it install?

The installed dependencies of the Zend Skeleton use symfony/console in version 2.6.6.

"anahkiasen/rocketeer" requires "illuminate/console" in a version ~4.2, which itself requires "symfony/console" in version 2.5.*.

Composer cannot install the new package because the installed version 2.6.6 of symfony/console will be kept, but is incompatible to the requirement of the depencencies of the new package (2.5.* does not allow version 2.6.6).

You can try to manually add your new package and then run `composer update`. If by chance the skeleton package would also allow symfony/console in version 2.5, this would resolve to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Fair enough, after second glance at the message and digging up some `depends` commands of composer, this cleared out for me. Thanks for your time. Any decent tools for remote deployment (cuz that Rocketeer.....)